# cookie is not set for subdomain

Tags: cookies

I have domain `mysite.com`, and subdomains `staging-api.mysite.com`, `staging-app.mysite.com` and `staging.mysite.com`.

In `https://staging.mysite.com` I send s request to `https://staging-api.mysite.com/webapi/v2/users`, which returns a response with cookies:

```
refresh_token_v2=eyJpdiI6IkYzRnNjM253NGhWNGhRTVB3VitPUUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOEN1WjBCd2J0ZWJ4NjFyTDcvTHlUbmlnTFc1eW51Um1kR3FyT2VZRkwvRlNNRHdWUzJMTm94M3BDVVUzMnh0TVk1bzQxbE1JV0I4TXM3bmxabWtPdmJPNFhlMGpLL0FkYjY0WVIxd09wVUE9IiwibWFjIjoiNzc1MTE0ZmQ2MzRmNDA2MjA5NGMyZDgyNjU1YjQ5Yjc0N2Q5YWM0YzdiODYxNzQxZjVkNGVhNDU3ZmY1Nzg4NiIsInRhZyI6IiJ9; expires=Tue, 01-Aug-2023 15:52:42 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/webapi/v2/auth; domain=staging-api.mysite.com; secure; httponly; samesite=none
```

After that, when I go to page `https://staging-app.mysite.com` and send request to `https://staging-api.mysite.com/webapi/v2/auth/refresh`, no cookie is sent:

```
Cookie:  
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IksrZmczZG1pdjh1ayszb0JrMHg1SHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTmxqSFl6cVlkaXdac0Iyb1NvOGxVMVZsMU1MbEdsekwrWnlpSUd0empZZ0cwTG93TXNrTkt1Q3pnS0wyaHFVaGo3YmxFbGJFeU5odFJCTkdyTXphaFArOUxiNllLWnJLQ2llOXJqam13TmVEd2dVQTcySlZwNWgwSjNtNEEwMUUiLCJtYWMiOiIwM2MwZmI3YjI4NWY1ZDJiNTk4NjJlOTNjMDhkYTJjM2M1YjZmYjI3ZGIyNmU2NzQ3MGJkMWQ2YTM3NDAzOWVhIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; LC_AR=eyJpdiI6Im1ZYUZVbVJ2UGlwN2ZTV0JpemUxM3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQmhQbHkvS3pKMTFrWnZDeEgxajJHZUt3SmRoUEIyVDBwSXhIWkpNZVREWHdaNHk1L1FFbjgvUkRRM2pKMmVzTlRLVjRWZjZuQVgyb2xodHZnR0VQVUNRYlUzVjZUdW5DUjdMRDhTb1k3Nnd4Mk5PQVZnL05qNFlLZ3YyQ09SQUsiLCJtYWMiOiJhZGI4ZjM3Mzg4YjczMmFmZGFlZjI0OWEwOTM1OTlmMmQ1YTkyN2QzYzA2ZDYzNmE3NDRhZTRmMGM3YWFjNWRjIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; _ga=GA1.1.2021473439.1690901563; _ga_LDYSFCE96S=GS1.1.1690901563.1.0.1690901563.0.0.0
```

Why is the cookie `refresh_token_v2` not being sent? I see that the params `domain`, `path`, `secure` are correct for my case